# Missing Upgrade Button In Google Cloud Platform Console

Tags: google-cloud-console

I got an email notifying me that my Google Cloud Console free trial is about to end in 7 days, but when I click the button to upgrade, it just takes me to the dashboard with no options to upgrade. Also the upgrade button that is supposed to appear on the top right is missing.

Could someone please advise how I can upgrade my account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade your account you would need to visit the billing tab in the navigation menu of the cloud console page, on the billing overview page there's an option to select manage billing.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I have looked in the place you are suggesting (Billing > Overview > Manage) many times, but the option to upgrade is not there.